# Unable to add reference of EasyNetQ on Unity Project

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, unity-game-engine, easynetq

Could anyone direct me to the the correct version of EasyNetQ which will work with Unity 5.x (.Net 3.5) project?

I have a unity 5.x project which is targeted to the .Net framework 3.5 (Unity 3.5 .net subset base class libraries).

I need to use the RabbitMQ system with my project.

But when I try to refer to the EasyNetQ (a client library which uses the RabbitMQ.client library to communicate with RabbitMQ server) to the project via NuGet Package manager, I get an error that it is not compatible to the targeted 3.5 .Net platform.

I have tried adding different versions of EasyNetQ with no luck. I am thinking that the latest version build will not work with .Net 3.5 framework.

Comment: What I'm about to say can be absolutely wrong, but I get that error sometimes, mostly with dll that I have built, and I solve it by manually browse the filesystem and adding the library

Comment: @Phathe01 do you have the EasyNetQ build for target platform : Unity 3.5 .net subset base class libraries? Seems the EasyNetQ project only targeted to the 4.0 and 4.5 platform.

Answer (score 1):

EasyNetQ has been recently updated to .NET 4.0 minimum, if you pick one of the older versions it might work. Could you try to install version `0.50.12.407`?

```
install-package EasyNetQ -version 0.50.12.407
```